# Write form textbox values to Word document doesn't work

Tags: forms, vba, textbox, userform

I have a user form for text phrases and I want to save the entered phrases upon closing the user form. For some reason it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 1") = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 2") = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 3") = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 4") = UserForm1.TextBox4.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 5") = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("QAS 1") = UserForm1.TextBox6.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("QAS 2") = UserForm1.TextBox7.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("GPE 1") = UserForm1.TextBox8.Value
ActiveDocument.Variables("GPE 2") = UserForm1.TextBox9.Value

Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

On initilization of user form I have the following code:

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 1").Value
UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 2").Value
UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 3").Value
UserForm1.TextBox4.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 4").Value
UserForm1.TextBox5.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("SPE 5").Value
UserForm1.TextBox6.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("QAS 1").Value
UserForm1.TextBox7.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("QAS 2").Value
UserForm1.TextBox8.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("GPE 1").Value
UserForm1.TextBox9.Value = ActiveDocument.Variables("GPE 2").Value

End Sub
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems the problem is the command "Unload". Actually I want to keep the entries and not unload them. How can you close a user form not using "Unload"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can you close a user form not using "Unload"?

You could use `UserForm1.Hide`

Comment: Yes. I used this and disabled the "X" button using this code: It works now.

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose _
  (Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
'   Prevents use of the Close button
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        MsgBox "Clicking the Close button does not work."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub